# Android Studio - Cannot resolve method 'setText(java.lang.Object)'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I Am Getting An Error in my code That Says **Cannot resolve method 'setText(java.lang.Object)'**. Does anyone know what causes this error and how i can fix it?

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


        //String str_phonenumber = txt_number.toString();
        //str_phonenumber = str_phonenumber.replaceAll("\\D+","");

      ArrayList phonenum = new ArrayList(results.get(0).getPhoneNumbers());
      

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == CONTACT_PICKER_REQUEST){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                results = MultiContactPicker.obtainResult(data);
                StringBuilder names = new StringBuilder(results.get(0).getDisplayName());
                for (int j=0;j<results.size();j++){
                    if(j!=0)

                        names.append(", ").append(results.get(j).getDisplayName());
                }

                //txt_number.set(phonenum);
                txt_number.setText(phonenum.get(0)); //ERROR HERE:  Cannot resolve method 'setText(java.lang.Object)'

                Log.d("MyTag", results.get(0).getDisplayName());
            } else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
                System.out.println("User closed the picker without selecting items.");
            }
        }
```

Comment: `setText()` takes a `String` or an `int`, not an arbitrary object. Perhaps you should be calling `toString()` on `phonenum.get(0)`.

Comment: @CommonsWare it fixes the error however it causes my app to crash. Any Ideas why? It Says: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0  at the ArrayList phonenum = new ArrayList(results.get(0).getPhoneNumbers()); line

Comment: if `.getPhoneNumbers()` returns something like a list or an array. then I guess you need to get() the element in that array and then convert it to string

Comment: When defining a container variable you should use generics like `ArrayList<String>` then the compiler knows what data type you want to store in a variable.

Comment: @Robert I Have tried that but in my Logcat is gives me an error after my app crashes saying java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Comment: you need to clarify this line `ArrayList phonenum = new ArrayList(results.get(0).getPhoneNumbers());`. What is `results`? and the code for `getPhoneNumbers()`?

Comment: @MehranBehbahani the code for results is =     List<ContactResult> results=new ArrayList<>();  and getPhoneNumbers() is a piece of code that should get me a set of selected phone numbers. Also <ContactResult> is an import i have import com.wafflecopter.multicontactpicker.ContactResult;

Comment: Bro this is not how you ask a question. Please add your complete `ContactResult` class to your question. Also add your previous comment to he question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for index out of bound is because your arraylist is empty but you are trying to get the first element of an empty array!!

Comment: I am quite new and also not very good at Android Studio. If you dont mind could you tell me how i can add an element?

Comment: you can simply use arraylist.add(element e) method.Tell me about your scenario maybe I can help you better.for example where do you start activity for results and where do you instantiate your list??

Comment: where have you instatiate results??